# How to automatically put function declaration in header file?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

In Delphi you write a function in 'implementation' and then you have to put that function in the 'interface' section also. Tedious but luckily there is a shortcut for that: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and Delphi will automatically do it. (Well this is a bit unreliable as it only works if you are a bit lucky.... but works in MOST cases)

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Class_Completion

C++ with its obnoxious header files makes this job even more unpleasant. But there is no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to help you. Can you automate this job, like in Delphi?

Comment: There is no automated option in C++Builder, no.

Comment: Whole Tomato Visual Assist integration is announced for C++ Builder 10.4, and then we'll see if this feature will be supported.

Comment: Removed [embarcadero] tag that was deleted before, see here - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377488/the-embarcadero-tag-has-been-burninated